# How to know if a Bluetooth piece can transmit?

Tags: bluetooth, mp3-player

So I got an MP3 player (technically MP4, but the screen is about the size of my thumb), but it's old and obviously doesn't support Bluetooth headsets.

Reason I wanted a Bluetooth headset was due to my earplugs' connection piece constantly breaking after a couple weeks.

Anyway, I found [this thingy](http://www.miniinthebox.com/3-5mm-usb-bluetooth-wireless-receiver-audio-music-adapter-car-home-aux-speaker_p2976716.html).
It says receiver in the name of the object, but "Music Receiver Transmitter" under "Accessory Type".

So my question is: will it be able to do what I want it to do? And most importantly: will it be able to connect to my Bluetooth headphones without any interface (like on a smartphone or PC)?

If this thing is incapable of doing what I need, can any of you recommend any other device that may work? (preferably no cables, since that would defeat the whole purpose)

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic because it's not directly a recommendation question, and asks for the capabilities of a specific device, which qualifies as a technical support request.